# TFS 2017 - package usage overview

Tags: package, nuget

is there a dashboard, that gives an overview of the usage of all nuget packages?! Let's say i have a nuget package (stored in my TFS) in 2 different versions. Now i want to know, which project(s) (stored in TFS too) use which version of the nuget package. 
Regards

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such a dashboard/widget to show an overview of the usage of all nuget packages.

However, you can add a **Markdown** widget to dashboard, then add the nuget packages' information for each project manually when create a new project.

Thus you can have an overview of the usage of all nuget packages for all the projects.

Please refer to this article to [Add widgets to a dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/add-widget-to-dashboard)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll have a look to the link.

Answer (score 0):

This question actually is more related to nuget then to TFS as i guess by "project(s)" you mean c# projects or something similar. Package management in TFS is just a regular nuget server. No nuget server knows about the detailed usages of managed packages other then the plain number of downloads (sometimes). Only the projects know which packages they use (via packages.config or packages.json).

So the answer to your question is: No, this is not possible (by automatic means).

You could only manually work around as Andy suggested.